# C#: override a property of the parent class

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I have a class that inherits from X509Certificate2. I want the NotAfter property to be in UTC rather than local time. I'm pretty new to C# and was wondering if what I have below is the best way of doing it?

```
internal class Certificate : X509Certificate2
{
    public new DateTime NotAfter 
    {
        get { return base.NotAfter.ToUniversalTime(); }
    }
```

**EDIT**
When I changed it to this:

```
public override DateTime NotAfter 
{
    get { return base.NotAfter.ToUniversalTime(); }
}
```

Resharper complained that "There is not suitable property for override"

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What's wrong with adding a `NotAfterUtc` property instead?

Comment: Agree with @LukeH -- you are trying to change the contract (meaning) of a property defined in the base class.  That is almost never a good idea.  A separate property makes much more sense to me.

Comment: Maybe it is better to wrap X509Certificate2 class instead of inherit from it. Otherwise what you have here is ok.

Comment: @swisstony that edit fails because the property in the base class is not marked as virtual.  Read up on inheritance as a topic, less the syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @LukeH Yes, I was thinking of doing that; just thought existing code would pick this up automatically, but no big deal to change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have done there is member hiding.  If the class you are deriving from has marked the property as `virtual`, or is overriding it from it's base (if it has one) you use the `override` keyword:

```
public override DateTime NotAfter
```

The member hiding can be used when the base class *has* marked it `virtual`, however if someone cast a reference of your class into the base class and accessed the member, they would bypass your `new` hiding.  With true inheritance using `override`, this problem does not occur.

As has been noted by someone, this property is not marked `virtual`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.notafter.aspx

Member hiding will allow you to get around this if people use your class directly, but the moment someone casts your class back to a base type, they get the base value:

```
class MyClass : Cert...

MyClass c = new MyClass();
DateTime foo = c.NotAfter; // Your newly specified property.

Cert cBase = (Cert)c;
foo = cBase.NotAfter; // Oops, base value.  Inheritance cures this, but only with virtual members.
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this way you are just hiding the property with a new one.

Please use "override" instead of "new". See here for details on the "new" keyword as modifier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

EDIT: As mentionned in the comment below, the property in X509Certificate2 is not marked as virtual, so overriding it is not possible in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Methods/Properties in C# are not virtual by default (like they are in Java). Are you sure your NotAfter property is defined as virtual in the base class?