# Inheriting fields from a base class C#

Tags: c#, oop

I'm having trouble getting a class to inherit fields from its parent class.

I want the BullFrog class and Toad class to inherit all attributes from Amphibian class, and then overwrite the weight attribute. I thought it inherited all traits from the parent class by default, what am I missing here?

```
public class Animal
    {
        public string sound { get; set; }
        public string move { get; set; }
        public string favSnack { get; set; }
        public double avgWeight { get; set; }
        public void Speak(string sound)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( $"I go {sound}.");
        }
        public void Move(string move)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"I {this.move} around the farm all day.");
        }
        public void Eat(string favSnack)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"I like to eat {favSnack}.");
        }
        public void Weight(int avgWeight)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"I usually weigh about {avgWeight}lbs.");
        }
      
    }
    //decide on four or more animals
    //for each animal decide on four or more methods
    public class Amphibian : Animal
    {
        string sound = "ribbit";
        string move = "hop";
        string favSnack = "flies";
        double avgWeight = .05d;

    }
    public class BullFrog : Amphibian 
    {
        double avgWeight = .375d;
    }

    public class Toad : Amphibian
    {
        double avgWeight = .175d;
    }
```

where did I go wrong? when I call the methods

```
BullFrog kermit = new BullFrog();
            kermit.Move(kermit.movement);
            kermit.Eat(kermit.favSnack);
```

I get "I around the farm all day" and two blank lines as the output.
My question is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: override a property of the parent class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943911/c-override-a-property-of-the-parent-class) BTW - you are also mixing properties and members.

Comment: Try making the properties public in Amphibian

Comment: Why are you ignoring the warnings that the compiler gives you about hiding inherited members? It's giving you a strong clue that you're not using your inherited members, and are instead re-declaring them.

Comment: Your fields lack access modifiers, in those cases they get the most restrictive one, which is `private`, which means you can't access those from outside the class. Make them at least `protected`.

Comment: Actually, there's a lot of warning on your program, you better fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the `virtual` and `override` keywords in C#. This is to be used in case you want to actually change the way the derived class moves. Go with the constructor way if it's just a string change.

```
public class Animal
{
     public virtual string move { get; set; }
```

```
public class Amphibian : Animal
{
     public override string move { get; set; } =  "hop";
```

Your line `string move = "hop";` is just declaring a private property inside the `Amphibian` class, which will not affect the base class in any way.

Another way to handle this would be to set the value in a constructor, but you should remember to always set the value in any constructor you are creating.

```
public class Animal
{
     public string move { get; set; }
 
     public Animal(string move) {
         this.move = move;
     }
```

And then

```
public class Amphibian : Animal
{
     public Amphibian(): base("hop") {
     }
```

Comment: Nitpick: `string move = "hop";` doesn't declare a property but a field.

Comment: you don´t need to make the property `virtual` to set its initial value.

Comment: Why overriding it when you can simply set some values in the constructor?

Comment: I think it is about properties as declared in the `Animal` class. I added both solutions, setting the value in constructor and overriding the behavior. The op can chose whichever suits his/her needs better.

Comment: + The overriding solution first came to mind as Movement `IS` a kind of behavior that I would expect to change from implementation to implementation.

Comment: If it's a behavior, I would rather go for a strategy pattern, then

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Design patterns like strategy are to be used in scenarios where there are indeed multiple strategies for the same object. Instead of creating subclasses, you change the algorithm. In cases like these simple OOP abstraction would suffice.